# Search for row having a column not set at null and created over x days ago

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table, Action with the following columns:

```
   Id | CommandID | CreationDate | AbandonId | OtherActionID 
_________________________________________________________
    1 | 1         | 2018-10-09   | Null      | 1
_________________________________________________________
    2 | 1         | 2018-10-08   | 1         | Null
```

The process is like this:

1) Each time there is an action on a command a new line is added to the Action table.

2) In case, the command is abandonned, a new line is added in the Action table with the AbandonId set.

3) An abandonned command can be reactivated again, and a new line is added to the Action table with the AbandonId as null and the OtherActionID set.

Now I need to get all the CommandID which has been abandonned over 15 days ago with no other action set on that command.

In the above example, the commandId should not be fetched since the latest action on the command is not abandonning.

However in the below example, it should:

```
   Id | CommandID | CreationDate | AbandonId | OtherActionID 
_________________________________________________________
    1 | 1         | 2018-10-09   | 1         | Null
_________________________________________________________
    2 | 1         | 2018-10-08   | Null      | 1
```

Any idea of how to do this in sql server?

Comment: Sample data and expected output will here!

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT act1.CommandID,
       act1.CreationDate,
       act1.AbandonID
FROM   Action act1
WHERE  act1.AbandonID IS NOT NULL
  AND  act1.CreationDate < DATEADD(day, -15, GETDATE()) -- Adjust it in order to get rid of the time
  AND  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   Action act2
                   WHERE  act2.CommandID = act1.CommandID
                     AND  act2.CreationDate > act1.CreationDate
                     AND  act2.AbandonID IS NULL
                     AND  act2.OtherActionID IS NOT NULL);
```

It returns all commands abandoned more than 15 days ago not having a successive other action.